# Spark sql very slow - Fails after couple of hours - Executors Lost

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying Spark Sql on a dataset ~16Tb with large number of files (~50K). Each file is roughly 400-500 Megs.

I am issuing a fairly simple hive query on the dataset with just filters (No groupBy's and Joins) and the job is very very slow. It runs for 7-8 hrs and processes about 80-100 Gigs on a 12 node cluster.

I have experimented with different values of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` from 20 to 4000 but havn't seen lot of difference.

From the logs I have the yarn error attached at end [1]. I have got the below spark configs [2] for the job.

Is there any other tuning I need to look into. Any tips would be appreciated,

Thanks

```
2. Spark config - 
spark-submit
--master yarn-client
--driver-memory 1G
--executor-memory 10G
--executor-cores 5
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=2
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2


1. Yarn Error:

16/04/07 13:05:37 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1459747472046_1618_02_000003. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459747472046_1618_02_000003
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

I have explored the container logs but did not get lot of information from it.

I have seen this error log for few containers but not sure of the cause for it.

```
1. java.lang.NullPointerException  at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockManager$$doStop(DiskBlockManager.scala:167)
2. java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RegisterExecutorFailed to org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RegisteredExecutor$
```

Comment: Can you describe your cluster specification, I think to know what might be going wrong.

Comment: Its a decent cluster - 12 node cluster, C3.4x Large.

Comment: so actually you are on EMR ?